# Can TFS 2010 be installed onto a single server and in a Workgroup (not AD)

Tags: windows-server-2008, team-foundation-server

currently, we're using TFS2010 at our office and we're about to move. Part of that move is a split of teams. Our team will get their own server(s). So we need to build our own TFS server and add our current projects to that.

Right now, our TFS server exists on TWO servers -> one for TFS and one for our Continuous Integration .. i think that's a build controller or something.

That really suxs for us  - having TWO servers instead of one for all our source control. We love CI and how it works (after the massive massive pain it was to get our VS2010 solution to CI + web Deploy) ... but it does work.

So - can we do this with ONE server? Also, we don't want to have an Active Directory. Will this also work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TFS Build Controller is designed so that it can be run on a workstation in small environments (See [this MS article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd793166.aspx)). Obviously this comes with the usual caveats about running anything on a workstation (lower performance, has to be online all the time, not backed up, liable to conflict with things), but it's a documented configuration that MS expects small teams will use.

The build controller should be kept separate from the TFS server itself for security and stability reasons - It's a host that builds and executes a changing code base and as such, that role should stay away from your code repository.

Regarding the lack of domain - Yes, TFS will install in workgroup mode.

Comment: Cheers mate :) Very helpful indead :) I fully agree with the rational with a build controller being kept separate - but when you're strapped for cash in a startup sometimes risk vs reality comes into play. It would be nice to have the options, even if the risk has been understood and accepted :) And for a Continuous Intergration scenario, we can't rely on workstation(s) being the BC's. But very helpful answer instead and it doesn't help our decision making :) Cheers again!

Answer (score -3):

PLEASE think a little more than "more than one server sucks". At least get virtual machines.

> That really suxs for us - having TWO
>   servers instead of one for all our
>   source control. We love CI and how it
>   works (after the massive massive pain
>   it was to get our VS2010 solution to
>   CI + web Deploy) ... but it does work.

Ah, o you want all that one one server to be sure to make it unstable? I isolate build controllers for the whole purpose I Can rebuild them should some upgrade fail. I have to install quite a lot of software on build servers, while the TFS server is "pure" and thus a lot more stable.

> Also, we don't want to have an Active Directory. Will this also work?

Ah. No. Get real. Complex Windows Scenarios = Active Directory. That said, what happens at your place? Get out. They don't split into teams, they tear the infrastructure apart. Even with multiple teams there is no reason you:

- ...can not have ONE active directory.  I maintain one in three locations and two are just ADSL linked.
- ...can not have some central admins which know what they do. TFS is a little more complex to set up.

Alternative:

Get ONE server which runs Hyper-V, install virtual machines for everything. I do that ;) Up to 3 physical machines now (2x16gb, 8 discs each, 1x64gb now 14 discs). Then you can still have separation.

Comment: wow. I've been here a while and have never found such a personally biased and aggressive post. *shocked* Also buddy - be careful about such assertions like *Get Out*, *Don't split teams - they tear the infra apart* etc. You have absolutely _NO_ idea about out the current context. Poor form, mate.

Comment: cripes, dude. Put a bit more time into your posts - not only is it hard to follow your reasoning, but they're riddled with grammatical errors, spelling errors, and typos. Ditto on the poor form.